# Where can you find the unit production for a town?

Tags: might-and-magic-heroes-6

Navigating a town's menu I can't find this information anywhere. Is there a way to see how many of each unit a given town is producing per week?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Heroes VI, creature production has been divorced from towns entirely, as recruitment is map-wide. This means, for instance, that "creatures produced by a town per week" is less useful than "creatures produced by your entire realm".

As far as I know, there's only support for the latter - clicking the arrow on the minimap will bring you to the kingdom overview screen, which will show you your current heroes, their armies, and your creature production.

Comment: And may I say, I love this feature in Heroes 6 more than basically any other change from Heroes 5. This completely obviates the need for "FedEx" heroes whose only purpose is to ship creatures from the back of your empire to the front, so that the real heroes can pick them up. Thank the gods.

Comment: In my opinion this feature makes the game less strategical and destroys athmosphere. It's realistic that you get supply problems if you are too far away from your home town. You had to plan how you get the troops and it was a great joy to take it finally.